# Files/Archive Manager application unable to extract .rar files

Tags: pantheon-files, release-odin

On Hera I had no issues extract either .rar files or .cbr files using Files/Archive Manager.

Now on Odin when I try to extact either I get an error saying "An error occured while extracting files. Parsing Filters is unsupported"

I have downloaded Ark from the AppCenter and the same files that fail with Archive Manager will extract fine with Ark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322776 suggests that this problem may be due to "Unrar" not being installed.